# How to remove returned object <_sre.SRE_Match object from Python re.search?

Tags: python, regex

The string is

> root      8251  7966  2 05:04 ?        00:10:47 java
> -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx16384m -Xms8192m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /external_text.jar

The regex pattern is

```
fullCmd = re.search("-Djava.*(?= -jar)", line)
```

returns

> root java Apr26 00:26:13 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(53, 204),
> match='-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx16384m -Xms8192m -XX>
> external_text.jar

I preferred to get only `-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx16384m -Xms8192m -XX` by exclude the returned strings which I don't know what's called?

Comment: Because _that's what `re.search()` returns._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong function here, and instead you should be using `re.findall` if you also want to extract the matching text:

```py
inp = "root 8251 7966 2 05:04 ? 00:10:47 java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx16384m -Xms8192m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /external_text.jar"
match = re.findall(r'-Djava\S+(?: -X[^\s:]+)+', inp)[0]
print(match)
# -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx16384m -Xms8192m -XX
```